Yet another questions for missing migration files
I inherited a Django app without the migration files. I suppose the app was developed with an older Django version that the one on the server.
The first time python manage.py makemigrations is executed it is successful and produces 0001_initial.py file
Migration (python manage.py migrate) or new executions of makemigrations
with existent 0001_initial.py fail with a weird error:
 File "/afat/afatprivate/AFATdashboard/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 223, in Migration
bases=(models.Model, AFATdashboard.models.__support),
AttributeError: module 'AFATdashboard.models' has no attribute '_Migration__support'

I searched for _Migration__support and found nothing useful.
The error is the same with an empty database too, so this related answer didn't solve the problem 
Code from 0001_initial.py, last line is 223
 migrations.CreateModel(
        name='EconCostoCorpiIdrici3',
        fields=[
            ('waterbodycode', models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='waterBodyCode', max_length=255, null=True)),
            ('waterbodyname', models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='waterBodyName', max_length=255, null=True)),
            ('numinterventi', models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, db_column='numInterventi', null=True)),
            ('numinterventiconcosto', models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, db_column='numInterventiConCosto', null=True)),
            ('costocorpoidrico2227', models.DecimalField(blank=True, db_column='costoCorpoIdrico2227', decimal_places=65535, max_digits=65535, null=True)),
            ('coperturafinanziariacorpoidrico', models.DecimalField(blank=True, db_column='coperturaFinanziariaCorpoIdrico', decimal_places=65535, max_digits=65535, null=True)),
            ('percentualecoperturafinanziaria', models.DecimalField(blank=True, db_column='percentualeCoperturaFinanziaria', decimal_places=65535, max_digits=65535, null=True)),
            ('waterbodycostconfidence', models.DecimalField(blank=True, db_column='waterBodyCostConfidence', decimal_places=65535, max_digits=65535, null=True)),
            ('costocorpoidrico2227color', models.TextField(blank=True, db_column='costoCorpoIdrico2227Color', null=True)),
            ('recid', models.TextField(db_column='recId', primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
        ],
        options={
            'db_table': 'ECON_costo_corpi_idrici_3',
            'managed': False,
        },
        bases=(models.Model, AFATdashboard.models.__support),
    ),

What can I do ?
UPDATE 1
My models.py starts this way:
class __support:

I'm wondering if support has become a keyword
Besides I'm testing a reduced model.py and I'm finding other errors. Most DecimalFields have these attributes:
decimal_places=65535, max_digits=65535

and I suspect these numbers are too high to be supported.

Please provide a [mre], to be specific show us some model code which will allow us to generate a migration like the one you get.

Show the declarations for the EconCostoCorpiIdrici3 model and whatever is in AFATdashboard.models

AFATdashboard.models is quite big with lots of models, don't know how to extract the relevant parts. The declarations for the EconCostoCorpiIdrici3 model is the same of that extracted from 0001_initial.py

As far as I know there is no way to upload a file here, AFATdashboard.models is decisely too big to be added as text. It si not easy for me to upload it elsewhere and link it, please tell me the parts you would like to check.

Reading the migration file it seems that the model you are using EconCostoCorpiIdrici3 has managed=False which means that django will not create the db tables for it, it will create the migration files though. You can read more about the managed option on the docs
I guess you could remove the managed=False and recreate the migrations

I tried but the end result is the same.  Replacing with managed=True a new line is added at the beginning of the file, import django.db.models.deletion, so the exception is report at line 224. Does anybody has an idea of what is _Migration__support  attribute ?

I have finally found a workaround.
At the beginning of models.py there is this class declaration:
class __support:

It begins with a double underscore, which turned out it has a special meaning in Django.
Lots of classes inherits from __support and inside the migration file 0001_initial.py the first one is that reported above, EconCostoCorpiIdrici3
bases=(models.Model, AFATdashboard.models.__support),

I replaced __support with _mySuperclass and the migration command was successful.
It was a trivial error which cost much time because there was no clue to its real cause.
